# How to reveal progressing border on window scroll

Tags: html, css

In this code title border is "spreading" on hover and I want to create the same effect on a scroll. How can I do this?

```css
.title {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #262626;
}

.title::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ED1C24, rgb(230, 7, 74));
}

.section-box:hover .title::before {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 2px;
  transition: 1s;
  background: #ED1C24;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-box" id="about">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="section-head">
      <h1 class="title">about us</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "spreading" or what exactly you're trying to achieve. Can you post an example of the title "spreading?" Do you mean the linear gradient?

Comment: yes, title bottom linear-gradient

Comment: https://codepen.io/pk000/pen/gOpwMWG

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "on scroll," but the animation you want is applied by the CSS psuedo-class `:hover`. There is no psuedo-class for scroll, so you'll need to probably involve Javascript.

The list of available CSS psuedo-classes [can be found here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) Try experimenting with them to see if they'll do what you want.

The [Javascript onscroll event can be found here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onscroll)